# How to return multiple values as JSON using python 3.8?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have to save a couple of different urls in some variable and then I have to return them from AWS Lambda function using json.dumps. I am trying the below method but it's giving me the error `"errorMessage": "unhashable type: 'dict'"`. Code is given below.

```
response1 = { "statusCode": 200, "message": "Audio File uploaded successfully", "Link": some_variable1}
response2 = { "statusCode": 200, "message": "Spectrograph uploaded successfully", "Link": some_variable2}
response3 = {response1, response2}
   return {
   'statusCode': 200,
   'body': json.dumps(response3)
   }
```

Any idea how to get it working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{response1, response2}` is a set literal, which requires items to be hashable. In this case response1, response2 are dictionary which is not hashable.

```py
>>> a_dictionary = {"statusCode": 200}
>>> {a_dictionary}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Instead of using set, you can use list or tuple which do not require items to be hashable.

```py
>>> [a_dictionary]
[{'statusCode': 200}]
>>> (a_dictionary,)
({'statusCode': 200},)
```

```py
response3 = [response1, response2]  # list
# or
response3 = (response1, response2)  # tuple
```